# C++ tokenizing madness with templates and virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

During refactoring of a rather large code-base my compiler came up with a great way to misunderstand me. This is a minimal example of what I am talking about:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
        virtual int get() = 0;
        template <typename T> int get(int i) { return 4 + i; }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
        virtual int get() { return 3; }
};

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
        Bar b;
        std::cout << b.get<char>(7) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.6, gcc 4.7, gcc 4.8 and gcc 4.9 all tokenize the "b.get(7)" as a comparison operator between "b.get" and "char".

```
template-test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
template-test.cpp:16:17: error: invalid use of non-static member function
  std::cout << b.get<char>(7) << std::endl;
                 ^
template-test.cpp:16:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
  std::cout << b.get<char>(7) << std::endl;
                     ^
```

(This is gcc 4.9, the others say something similar)

Is this supposed to work?

The work-around I found was to declare the templated "get" in both the base and the derived class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name `get` in the derived class hides the name `get` in the base class. Hence, the function template `get()` is not found when performing name lookup, and the compiler can only interpret those tokens the way you've seen.

You can use a `using` declaration in your `Bar` class to fix that:

```
class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    using Foo::get;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    virtual int get() { return 3; }
};
```

Here is a [*live demo on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/318982478154bef1).

If you cannot modify the definition of `Bar` because it is not under your control, I guess you could qualify the call to `get()`:

```
std::cout << f.Foo::get<char>(7) << std::endl; // get() template is found now.
```

See [*here*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88666683a157da05) for a live demo. Another option is to perform the call through a pointer or reference to `Foo`:

```
Bar b;
Foo& f = b;
std::cout << f.get<char>(7) << std::endl; // get() template is found now.
```

Once again, [*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92b523338e3e8723).

Comment: This "overloading into base class" is something that I have heard about but obviously do not think about often enough. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @PhilippT.: I guess you can search for "name hiding" to learn more about it. Cheers :)

Comment: How about `std::cout << b.Foo::get<char>(7) << std::endl;`?

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, yeah, haven't thought of that one. Let me add it, thanks.